# Making UserControls accessible in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, accessibility

I have a WPF form, which consists of a grid of two columns.

In the left-hand column are the control labels, and in the right-hand column are my controls.

The controls are all UserControls. In the simplest case, some of these controls simply wrap existing WPF controls such as the textbox, so that they all implement a common interface.

When the form is generated, I have code like this to set the label for the associated control, where newControl is the created UserControl and ctl.Caption simply returns the required label text:

```
Label newLabel = new Label();
newLabel.Content = ctl.Caption + ":";
newLabel.Target = newControl;
```

One problem is that setting the Target doesn't actually work. If I have an underscore in the caption, the mnemonic key doesn't set focus to the wrapped control. One workaround for this may be to manually set the focus to the wrapped control within the UserControl code - but...

The biggest problem is accessibility. Screenreaders such as JAWS, and Windows built-in Narrator, do not read the control caption when the control receives focus.

I have had a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg712258.aspx - which provides a lot of detail, but no helpful examples. It has a lot of stuff about *custom* controls, which is surely overkill for a simple *user* control?

So, how can I "attach" my labels correctly to my UserControls?

You can browse the code for the entire project at http://quest.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/676933506953 - the particular code is in the EditorControls project, and the UserControls are instantiated in ElementEditor.xaml.cs.

Comment: I would use the decorator pattern, as it will allow you 'wrap' the controls in XAML (i.e. don't have to create custom controls). I will post an example later today after work.

Answer (score 1):

Your newControl is of type Control that doesn't allow you to add additional content. 
If you want to add some content to it you need to use a class that supports it, like ContentControl or Panel (for multiple childs) you can implement you own control that implements the IAddChild interface.

A simple solution for you problem could be :

```
<UserControl x:Class="UIMocks.MyCustomControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <StackPanel x:Name="content"/>
</UserControl>
```

The code-behind

```
[ContentProperty("Children")]
public partial class MyCustomControl : UserControl
{
    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public UIElementCollection Children { get { return content.Children; } }
}
```

and then you can use

```
MyCustomControl newControl = InitialiseEditorControl(ctl);
...
Label newLabel = new Label();
newLabel.Content = ctl.Caption + ":";
newControl.Children.Add(newLabel);
```

Comment: AddChild is protected on ContentControl, so it cannot be accessed in my AddControlToGrid function. And a UserControl cannot be cast to a Panel. Furthermore, it appears from the documentation that IAddChild is deprecated in .net 4.

Comment: You're right IAddChild is now obsolete, it has been replaced with e ContentProperty attribute. Thanks for ponting it out.
And I was no trying to say that he should cast his usercontrol to a Panel, just stating that he could use a control that has a content like the Panel (which is abstract and can't be used directly)

Answer (score 0):

hmmm I tried to reproduce your issue on a small test project, but for me it works... so I guess you'll have to give more details on how your userControls are built. Here is what works for me:

I created an Empty project (just the App and Window files, as usual) and set up a grid with 2 columns in my window:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Name="Window"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <Grid Name="MyGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

then created a userControl that extends the wpf TextBox class:

```
<TextBox x:Class="Test.MyTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

</TextBox>
```

and:

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class MyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(MyTextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
        public string Caption
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
        }

        public MyTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

it's basically a textbox with a "Caption" dp.

and now in My window's code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyTextBox tb = new MyTextBox { Caption = "_Foo", Width = 100 };
    Label lb = new Label { Content = tb.Caption + ":", Target = tb };

    MyGrid.Children.Add(lb);
    MyGrid.Children.Add(tb);

    Grid.SetColumn(lb, 0);
    Grid.SetColumn(tb, 1);
}
```

and with this, I do get focus on the TB when I press ALT + F (I can even see the _ under the F of "Foo" in the Label when just pressing ALT)

So I guess your issue has to do with your UserControls themselves and how they are built (what Template for instance)

**Edit:**

If your control is not extending an existing control but rather *contains* a WPF control, the issue is probably on the Focus method. You should add a Focus() method that sets the focus on the right part of your control when the control itself gets the focus.

code (for a UserControl containing a textbox that you want to get the focus for instance):

```
<TextBox x:Class="Test.MyTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Content="foo" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBox Name="TextBoxPart" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid> 

</TextBox>
```

code behind

```
public partial class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(MyTextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
    public string Caption
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
    }

    public MyTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxPart.Focus();
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**
I had an issue once, to transfer the focus to a subcontrol in a dataGridCell, and here is what I did in the template:

```
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
     <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
          <Setter TargetName="TextBoxPart" Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxPart}" />
     </Trigger>
 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

you could try adding this to your template. This should transfer your focus alright.

as for the accessibility, I don't think this will help, but I do not see any way of achieving what you want :-/

Comment: In my case, I'm not extending any existing controls, just wrapping them. So maybe I have for example some MyCustomTextBoxControl, which may *contain* a textbox, but doesn't derive from it (maybe because it also has a button or something next to it)

Comment: Thanks David, I've just given that a go, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. And even then, accessibility is still broken - focussing on the textbox still won't read out the label caption when using Narrator or JAWS.

Comment: darn... I'll give further thought to your issue tomorrow

Comment: Thanks David. If it helps (may be overkill), you can download the entire source code from http://quest.codeplex.com - the problem code is in the EditorControls project, and the UserControls are instantiated in ElementEditor.xaml.cs.

Comment: I finally found the piece of code I was looking for, see my 2nd edit. Hopefully this will solve at least half of your problem. As for the rest...